# Create some default facts from another fact to be able to retract some instances

Tags: prolog

I am using SWI-Prolog. I have list of facts in my database:

```
 a(r).
 a(s).
 a(t).
```

Now I want Prolog to insert a fact `b(X)` for any `X` where `a(X)` holds, so that I can interactively retract some fact `b(s)` or `b(t)`. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

The quick answer is:

```
?- forall(a(X), assert(b(X)))
```

However, notice that `b/1` must be declared to be a dynamic predicate (i.e., a predicate whose clauses can be asserted/retracted at run-time). This is declared in the following way:

```
:- dynamic(b/1).
```

Comment: Thanks to Paulo for fixing my typo. I regularly swap `pred/1` and `pred(_)`-notations in Prolog :-(

Comment: This Link says, ist one should use "foreach"

Comment: @Patrick Why do you believe variable bindings are needed here?